# Android: Swipe/Drag over multiple textViews in a GridView

Tags: android, kotlin, gridview, swipe, swipe-gesture

For a hobby project, I assembled a `GridView` that contains multiple `TextView`s each containing a single letter. When the user swipes across the grid, a String should be constructed from the letters, similar to the behaviour of a swipe lock pattern or a swipe keyboard:

[image: App Screenshot]

I'm using a Board Adapter that overrides the `getView` and `getItem` functions to generate the `TextView`s dynamically, where `board` wraps a 2D-Array that's automatically filled with the letters:

```
    override fun getItem(position: Int): String {
        return board.getString(getCol(position),getRow(position))
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        val textView : SquaredTextView

        textView.text = getItem(position)
        textView.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        textView.textSize = 40f

        return textView
    }
```

I don't want to use hacky methods that require manually checking if the x- and y- coordinates of a touch event are within the bounding box of one of the `TextView`s like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49499360/swiping-over-multiple-textviews). What kind of Listeners can I use in order to track the touch events of the swipe gestures across multiple `TextView`s, and build a String from their contents?

**Some excerpts of what I tried so far:**

I subclassed `TextView` to log `onTouchEvent`, `onHoverEvent` etc. to console, but only touch events are fired, and the touch gets cancelled as soon as the swipe gesture leaves the `TextView` it started on:

```
2020-10-29 19:06:22.059 5169-5169/com.example.myfirstapp D/Touch/L: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=103.94824, y[0]=116.98364, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=3726741, downTime=3726741, deviceId=0, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
2020-10-29 19:06:22.119 5169-5169/com.example.myfirstapp D/Touch/L: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=94.778076, y[0]=137.42896, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=3, eventTime=3726841, downTime=3726741, deviceId=0, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
2020-10-29 19:06:22.136 5169-5169/com.example.myfirstapp D/Touch/L: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=918.45154, y[0]=162.47711, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=2, eventTime=3726858, downTime=3726741, deviceId=0, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
```

I also tried adding an `OnItemClickListener` to the `GridView`, but that never get's fired. When using an `OnTouchListener` on the `GridView`, I can't find a way to figure out the individual `TextView`s from the touch events.

I've also searched the internet and StackOverflow for my problem, but just found results like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121878/how-to-select-multiple-items-in-gridview-with-single-swipe-of-finger-in-android) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47576829/gridview-selecting-multiple-items-on-gesture-swipe), where none of them have an accepted answer. If this has been answered somewhere already, feel free to point me to it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: actually it seems `(x,y)` coordinate based detection is quite well used as also in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104301/ontouchlistener-for-multiple-textviews-inside-tablerow to use `id` of views have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42923286/touch-listener-on-multiple-textviews other option could be to use canvas